# Changing a template return type appears to have an effect on an overload resolution

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, decltype

Have been writing an arithmetic wrapper that could help detecting over/underflow errors, however stuck with a rather devious problem in the process.

Suppose we have a class, that handles everything that is able to cause an overflow via some overloaded operators and is implicitly castable to the underlying type for everything else. This example contains only a binary plus operator:

```
template<typename T_>
class Wrapper
{
    public:
    Wrapper(T_ val_) : m_value(val_) { } // converting constructor
    operator T_(void) const { return m_value; } // underlying type conversion
    // some other methods

    // binary plus operators:
    template<typename U_>
    const Wrapper<decltype(T_() + U_())> operator +(U_ val_) const
    {
        // supposed to handle 'Wrapped + Unwrapped' case
        return m_value + val_;
    }
    template<typename U_>
    const Wrapper<decltype(T_() + U_())> operator +(Wrapper<U_> other_) const
    {
        // supposed to handle 'Wrapped + Wrapped' case
        return m_value + other_.m_value;
    }

    template<typename U0_, typename U1_>
    friend const Wrapper<decltype(U0_() + U1_())> operator +(U0_ val_, Wrapper<U1_> wrapper_)
    {
        // supposed to handle 'Unwrapped + Wrapped' case
        return val_ + wrapper_.m_value;
    }

    private:
    T_ m_value;
};
```

This (if I didn't miss something while pasting it here) compiles fine and works
as expected in situations like these (every possible one of them, basically):

```
Wrapper<int> val = 3.14f;
::std::cout << val + 42 << ::std::endl; // Wrapped + Unwrapped
::std::cout << 42 + val << ::std::endl; // Unwrapped + Wrapped
::std::cout << val + val << ::std::endl; // Wrapped + Wrapped
```

However, whenever I try to make an alias for the `decltype(...)` part of either the 'Wrapped + Unwrapped' or the 'Unwrapped + Wrapped' for example like this:

```
template<typename T0_, typename T1_>
struct Result
{
    typedef decltype(T0_() + T1_()) Type;
};

template<typename T_>
class Wrapper
{
    //...
    template<typename U_>
    const Wrapper<typename Result<T_, U_>::Type> operator +(U_ val_) const
    //...
    template<typename U0_, typename U1_>
    friend const Wrapper<typename Result<U0_, U1_>::Type> operator +(U0_ val_, Wrapper<U1_> wrapper_)
    //...
};
```

the 'Wrapped + Wrapped' example doesn't want to compile, because the overload resolution appears to change towards the undesired variant. It throws an error about unavailability of a default constructor for `Wrapper<int>`, impying the attempt to use either the 'Wrapped + Unwrapped' or 'Unwrapped + Wrapped', both of which are not suited to handle the case in question properly.

And that confuses me greatly as it looks like change in a return type leads to a change in an overload resolution behavior. Will appreciate any advice regarding the matter.

Comment: The undesirable overloads were SFINAE'd away; now they aren't, because the potentially invalid expression has been moved into `Result`'s definition and outside the immediate context.

Comment: So I was wrong in a first place to presume that the 'Wrapped + Wrapped' variant will be considered as a more suitable one for resolving the overload in such situation. Thak you for the answer.

Comment: It may well be a better overload (due to partial ordering etc.), but you don't even get there: you trigger a hard error trying to form the set of candidates.

Comment: there is an ambiguity between the `friend` version of the operator (when `U0_` is `Wrapper<int>`) and the operator you intended for the "wrapped + wrapped" case.

Comment: There's a separate issue: the definition of that `friend` function template needs to be moved out of the class template's definition; otherwise instantiating two `Wrapper`s will cause a multiple definition error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's roughly how overload resolution works:

1. Name lookup to find candidate functions and function templates.
2. Deduce template arguments for each function template, and substitute deduced arguments into the template to generate a single function template specialization as the candidate. Throw out any function template for which deduction fails (including substitution failure).
3. Compare the candidates. Pick the best one or complain if there isn't one.

If step 2 triggers a hard error - by forming an invalid construct outside the immediate context of the function template signature - then your program is ill-formed; you never get to step 3. It doesn't matter if the candidate wouldn't have been chosen in step 3 if the error wasn't there.

Here, `decltype(T_() + U_())` was in the immediate context originally. Therefore, when `U_` got deduced to `Wrapper<...>` and substituted into the signature, that expression is ill-formed, but the error is in the immediate context and so it's a substitution failure. But when you move that expression into a separate class template `Result`, the error is no longer in the immediate context of the function template's signature, so it's a hard error instead.

If you don't want to repeat the expression multiple times, use an alias template:

```
template<class T, class U>
using result = decltype(T() + U());
```

Comment: Thank you again for this doubtlessly helpful answer. It exhaustively explains the problem I'm having. It's very frustrating to not being able to learn all the template specifics, as I absolutely have to finish the thing I'm working on asap.

P.S: I know about the template aliasing, the srtuct is there for some additional static methods.